# How do a normal function and arrow function differ around _proto_ constructors?

Tags: javascript, constructor, arrow-functions

```js
let anonymous = function () {
    return 'hello'
};

let f = () => 'world';

console.log(new anonymous['__proto__'].constructor());
console.log(new f['__proto__'].constructor());


console.log(anonymous());
```

Both functions return a function with the name is `anonymous` when I try to create new instance of it.

My question: when I call `anonymous()` function, why doesn't it hit to the second constructor (arrow function)?

Comment: your question is convoluted and confusing. they are 2 different objects and why would calling anonymous execute f()?

Comment: What do you mean by "why doesn't it hit to the second constructor"? What does "it" refer to?

Comment: Arrow functions are not constructors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [[Prototype]] of both functions is `Function.prototype`. In that sense, function expressions and arrow functions do not differ.

```js
let anonymous = function () {
  return 'hello'
};
let f = () => 'world';
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(anonymous) === Function.prototype); // true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(f) === Function.prototype); // true
```

And `Function.prototype.constructor` is of course `Function`.

So you are doing `new Function()`, which creates a function which does nothing. That useless function is called `anonymous` because it has no name, but it's not the function in the `anonymous` variable.